# Migration from AWS Postgresql to ElasticSearch using AWS DMS

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, aws-dms

To improve the read performance, we are synching RDS Postgresql data to AWS ElasticSearch.  Used AWS DMS for it. It's working fine. But Joining tables is a challenge. We need a solution to denormalize the data and put it in elastic search using AWS DMS. For example, In customer and order tables in PostgreSQL should be one record in ElasticSearch.